# Generate permutations for forgotten LUKS pw

Tags: open-source, password-recovery

I encrypted my SSD with LUKS ~9 years ago. I wrote down my password on a piece of paper back then. Since then I used this password to boot my computer every day. It has 32 random characters that I generated when creating it.

I never really `knew` the password. It was just kind of muscle memory. My fingers knew how to type it, as I did it every day for a period of 9 years. Now, somehow I forgot how to type it. It sounds ridiculous but I can't figure it out anymore. I am still typing 32 characters, but it seems that they are wrong. The paper I wrote the password on 9 years ago is lost. I can't find it and I think I must have thrown it away by mistake.

It is not as I don't know anything of the password anymore. I am still typing something that is 32 characters long and I guess I am just doing some minor mistakes. Maybe using the `shift` key on the wrong places or misstyping 2-3 keys.

I thought that there might be a software that could generate permutations of my password, depending on the keyboard layout. Choosing keys that are next to the characters on my keyboard. So if I could generate this smart permutations I could just brute force them and test if I find the password. Does anyone know if there is a software like this? It could also be that the keyboard layout is in a different language. But I am pretty sure, that I did set it to `german qwertz` layout when setting up my system back then.

If I had my `permutations.txt` I could do something like this:

```
set -x
while read pass; do
  printf "%s" $pass | cryptsetup luksOpen --test-passphrase luksHeader.bin $@ && echo Success && break;
done < permutations.txt
```

This is what I am currently typing. The `wrong` password:
`q28n?CWe_bnGzmUF2YBYyh3dS!$a85m%`

I think that I make the mistakes in this sequence `bnGzmUF2YBY`.

Here is my `luksHeader.bin`: https://file.io/4wHQedlccvhE

If anyone knows a nice script for generating permutations like this, that would be awesome. Or if you got any other advice. I could try to write a script on my own, but I thought there might be something more sophisticated out there already. I tried googling it but couldn't find anything fitting.

Because in my current situation I am fu****. I can't access any of my files.